# Exact use of Spring Expression Language

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, el

I am trying to learn `Spring`, so from [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#expressions-ref-literal) I got this example,

```
ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();

// evals to "Hello World"
String helloWorld = (String) parser.parseExpression("'Hello World'").getValue();
```

But I didn't understand it exact usage, 'cause I can better declare it as

```
String helloWorld = "Hello World";
```

So what is the exact use of above `SpEL`?

Where can I use it better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That particular SpEL *is* useless. It's useful when the expression that you pass to the parser comes from some external source, such as an annotation value or an XML attribute. A comprehensive explanation of ELs is way too broad for Stack Overflow, but I suggest looking at [Thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html) for an example of how EL can be useful.

(Note also that it's much better to use `getValue(String.class)` instead of casting, both because it's safer and because you can take advantage of automatic type conversion.)

Answer (score 4):

Spring Expression Language is used mainly in view layer like JSP, Thymeleaf. You can manipulate java object easily in view layer with SpEL. If you want to evaluate SpEL expression in java layer, you can use `ExpressionParser` to get the outcome.

Generally we want to keep view layer as much clean as possible(Don't want to evaluate complex logical operation). But sometimes little manipulation is must needed. In that case SpEL becomes handy.

Comment: It's used widely in view layers, but it's also used in lots of other contexts, such as annotation expressions (for security advice or cache specifications) and workflow specifications (such as Spring Web Flow flows).